# How can disable the password filed ? ( laravel )

Tags: laravel

I've system don't required the password input just one input 
when I login , so I created this:

```
public function do_login()
{
    if (auth()->attempt(['user_id' => request('user_id')])) {
        return redirect('home');
    } else {
        session()->flash('erorr', trans('Your Id Incorrect'));
        return redirect('/')->withInput();
    }
} //ends of do_login
```

and this is the error appears to me > 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7Fu4.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Auth's `attempt` without a password.

Since you're letting anyone in with just the ID, all you need is:

```
auth()->loginUsingId(request('user_id'))
```

You may want to look up the ID in your database first, or `loginUsingId` should throw an exception you can try/catch for.

If `user_id` doesn't correspond to the `id` column of your `users` table, you may need a slightly different approach:

```
$user = User::where('user_id', request('user_id'))->first();
auth()->login($user);
```